# Generate random element from list with no more than one repetition of one element

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a pattern whose vocabulary can consist of only `'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' or '*'`, characters can repeat any number of times but the catch is that resulting the pattern must have at least one letter.

I tried with random module and this is the closest I came to what I want:

```
random.sample(set(vocabulary), 5)
Out[30]: ['A', 'D', '*', 'B', 'C']
```

Ideally I would like to see output like:

```
A***
ABAB
ABC*
```

and so on

how can I go about this?

Comment: Should the letter/letters always be at the beginning?

Comment: No it can be anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you want the product of your list element, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) :

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> voc=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '*']
>>> for pro in product(voc,repeat=5):
...    print ''.join(pro)
*AAAA
*AAAB
*AAAC
*AAAD
*AAA*
*AABA
*AABB
*AABC
 .
 .
```

And if you just want to get ride of equal subsets you can use the following list comprehension, for example:

```
>>> voc=['C', 'D', '*']
>>> list(product(voc,repeat=3))
[('C', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'D'), ('C', 'C', '*'), ('C', 'D', 'C'), ('C', 'D', 'D'), ('C', 'D', '*'), ('C', '*', 'C'), ('C', '*', 'D'), ('C', '*', '*'), ('D', 'C', 'C'), ('D', 'C', 'D'), ('D', 'C', '*'), ('D', 'D', 'C'), ('D', 'D', 'D'), ('D', 'D', '*'), ('D', '*', 'C'), ('D', '*', 'D'), ('D', '*', '*'), ('*', 'C', 'C'), ('*', 'C', 'D'), ('*', 'C', '*'), ('*', 'D', 'C'), ('*', 'D', 'D'), ('*', 'D', '*'), ('*', '*', 'C'), ('*', '*', 'D'), ('*', '*', '*')]
>>> list(i for i in product(voc,repeat=3)if len(set(i))>1)
[('C', 'C', 'D'), ('C', 'C', '*'), ('C', 'D', 'C'), ('C', 'D', 'D'), ('C', 'D', '*'), ('C', '*', 'C'), ('C', '*', 'D'), ('C', '*', '*'), ('D', 'C', 'C'), ('D', 'C', 'D'), ('D', 'C', '*'), ('D', 'D', 'C'), ('D', 'D', '*'), ('D', '*', 'C'), ('D', '*', 'D'), ('D', '*', '*'), ('*', 'C', 'C'), ('*', 'C', 'D'), ('*', 'C', '*'), ('*', 'D', 'C'), ('*', 'D', 'D'), ('*', 'D', '*'), ('*', '*', 'C'), ('*', '*', 'D')]
```

Comment: Yes! that's the behaviour I want but I also get ****, maybe I can just elimiate that with a if check statement? or is there another way to cleverly avoid all **** pattern? 
Thank you, now the python docs about it makes sense!

Comment: @sindhus welcome! i add the link!, yep that is the last result! the `itertools` module provide variant functions like `permutations` and `combinations` you can find all of them in wiki!

Answer (score 0):

```
chars=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '*']
s=""
L = len(chars)
for i in range(0,5):
    s += chars[random.randrange(0,L)]

# now ensure that a character is present by setting a random character
s[random.randrange(0,5)] = chars[random.randrange(0,L-1)]
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, you always should provide some explanation for why it does so.